# Avoiding creating additional variables for the object with this and methods inside the object

Tags: javascript, object, variables, refactoring, this

I have created a timer object with different timer methods, and I am fully happy how it works. However, I am unhappy with the code quality. I cannot understand how I can get the same working methods without creating additional variables, in particular the property `intervalId` and the function `resetSecAddMin`. Is it possible to have this solution working without these additional variables?

The code:

```
const timer = {
  secondsPassed: 0,
  minsPassed: 0,
  intervalId: null,
  startTimer() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      const resetSecAddMin = () => { this.secondsPassed = 0; this.minsPassed += 1 };
      this.secondsPassed < 59 ? this.secondsPassed += 1 : resetSecAddMin();
      }, [1000]);
  },
  getTime() {
    return this.secondsPassed < 10 ? `${this.minsPassed}:0${this.secondsPassed}` : `${this.minsPassed}:${this.secondsPassed}`;
  },
  stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  },
  resetTimer() {
    this.secondsPassed = 0;
    this.minsPassed = 0;
  },
};
```

I hope this question will contribute some value to the community. I believe that writing a readable code is not less important than creating working solutions.

Comment: You want to remove the shared state that is the only way to have different methods work with the same data? I'm not sure how you expect stuff like `stopTimer` to work without having access to the timer ID. The parts in this code I'd change are nothing to do with the shared properties.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need any timer. On startTimer() method you record start time `this.startTime = Date.now()`. And then inside getTime() you get the delta in milliseconds `var delta = Date.now() - this.startTime`. It will be in milliseconds, but you can divide by 1000 to get seconds and figure out minutes too by division.